# Calculating energy using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, energy, glcm

Energy, which is as follows:

[image]

can be found based on the [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) documentation using:

```
stats = graycoprops(glcm, properties)
```

For example, I typed this:

```
>> a = [1 2; 3 4]

a =

     1     2
     3     4

>> stats = graycoprops(a, {'energy'})

stats =

    Energy: 0.3000
```

If we want to do this *manually*, how did we get the **energy** value shown above?

This is the part I didn't get clearly.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not wrong:

```
ans=sum(a(:).^2)/sum(a(:)).^2
```

Comment: are you absolutely sure about that formula? I've tested it and it's not properly working... sorry for posting this as an answer, i can't comment yet. Comment from [user2205242](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2205242/user2205242).

Comment: @ user2205242, so it is "my word" that you seek? you have an exact expression (in the answer) and you have a built in function (in the question), you can easily test with an input such as `a=randi(100,100,100);`  But why trust me (or anyone else for that matter)? trust your understanding.

Comment: i need a reference paper where formula of energy is provided.

Answer (score 0):

In an energy network, there is a supply point (i) and a receiver point (j). If we follow this rule that the energy carried out between these two-point, then according to energy conservation law the total energy consumption at node "i" should be equal to total energy supplied from node "j". I called it energy flow due to the concept of sending to receiving points in an energy system.
Then,  "i" is the sender and the "j" is the receiver of the power we can write a summation of the inlet energy flow minus outlet energy flow (demand):

```
Total_Power = sum(Inlet_energy(:,:))-sum(Outlet_energy(:,:));
print (Total_Power);
```

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.